# Session not staying active in my web application

Tags: session, servlets

In my web application the JSESSION isn't staying active. I have enabled a JDBC Store on tomcat but this has still not fixed it. Any other suggestions.
Thanks in Advance 
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSESSION has to do with the cookie that identifies an active HttpSession in the container. I think your problem is nothing to do with how the container stores the session. The container times out a session after 30 minutes of activity by default. If you want to increase that, add this to web.xml:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```